# time series of xy-plots

Tags: java, swing

Does anybody know a Java library which supports graphics shown below on the photo(I program in Java). I want to create multiple xy-plots in a time sieries with 3d view ?
In principle I have got no idea how to create such thing. I already know that Jfreechart does not support this kind of graphic output and visualisation.

http://www.imgbox.de/show/img/I59uK1toSy.gif

Comment: Google it and you'll surely find it... If there is any...

Comment: Of course I did, but I am not sure if scaVis or Jzy3d supports this kind of graphics.

Comment: Use them to check them and please add an image description.. so that people can understand that what you want

Comment: it seems to be that the photo is not visible, in principle they are xy-plots shifted along a track in z-direction... so may be as some kind of pseudo-3D.

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/652089/GUI/java/time-series-xy-plots)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GoogleVis](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq) with it's [data source lib](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_about)

Comment: Well may be it is a solution, but how to combine it with Java ? There is still an unanswered question about Java API and GoogleVis from @tanmay misra posted in Nov 2014

Comment: Maybe a web service and using the GoogleVis as a view for your graph in a browser?  Else you'll probably have to build a Swing (or something else) component.

Comment: It should be an application running on windows PC.

Comment: You can run a web server on a PC, you'll just have to decide what framework you are going to use, Google, ect, seems to use web frame works.  Else hunt for a library that can do it in swing etc or do it yourself ;-)